# shared preference is not created by the program

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

in the following program, what i am trying to do is:
i want to store a list of names in shared preference

when the app starts for the first time, it should create a shared preference by name "profile_names"

and subsequently , when the app starts for next times, it should check if the sharedprefernces is there or not
if it is present is should fetch the list from the preference and give it to the listview.

But it is not working ..... where have i gone wrong?

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profilespage);

File f= new File("/data/data/neeraj.cardXchange.Basic/shared_prefs/profile_names");

if(f.exists()){
    Toast.makeText(this, "prefernce already created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    profile_names= getSharedPreferences("profile_names", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        try {
            myarraylist = getArrayList(mycontext, key);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


else{

         Toast.makeText(this, "prefernce  created now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         profile_names= getSharedPreferences("profile_names", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);


        }



String [] name_list = myarraylist.toArray(new String[myarraylist.size()]);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String>(this, R.layout.textview, name_list);
setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

here , i have used toast messages  to keep a check on how things proceed
every time the toast message from my "else" gets executed and the shared preference is not created
i have checked it using DDMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to commit the created shared preference, first you have store values in shared preferences and then commit it so that I can retain values that  can be used in other activities. here is small example to create and access shared preferences

To create:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("UMSPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("UserId", login);  
                    editor.putString("password", password);
                    editor.commit();
```

to access

```
String userid = getSharedPreferences("UMSPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE).getString("UserId", login);
            String paswrd = getSharedPreferences("UMSPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE).getString("password", password);
```

Comment: even if I don't want to store any values when it is first created? do I have to commit it at that time also? I want to create a blank file at first?